# Nonsmooth initial data in the conservation laws, their approximations and limits

Tags: limits, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

In the book by **R. LeVeque: "Numerical methods for conservation laws", Birkhauser, (1992), 2nd edition,** in the Subsection 3.1.2 called "*Nonsmooth data*", the author talks about possibilities for finding generalized solutions of the conservation laws when we have nonsmooth initial data. On $22^{nd}$ page he says: "One possibility is to approximate nonsmooth data $u_0(x)$ by a sequence of smooth functions $u^{\epsilon}_0(x)$, with $\parallel  u^{\epsilon}_0(x)- u_0 (x) \parallel_{L^1} <\epsilon \: \mbox{as} \: \epsilon \rightarrow 0$... Unfortunately, this approach of smoothing the initial data will not work for nonlinear
problems."

**My (nonlinear) problem is this:** let's say we have conservation law
$$\begin{cases}
 u_t+f(u)_x=0, \\[2ex] 
 u(x,0)=u_0 (x),
\end{cases}$$

where $u_0$ is nonsmooth Riemann initial data
$$u_0(x)= \begin{cases}
 u_l, x<0, \\[2ex]
 u_r, x>0,
\end{cases}$$ 
where $u_l$ and $u_r$ are constants.

We approximate the Riemann data with a smooth data that depends on some parameter $\epsilon$, i.e. we change $u_0$ with $u^{\epsilon}_0(x)$. In my case, the new initial data $u^{\epsilon}_0(x)$ are in the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R})$, where $s$ is integer bigger than five. This is now a Cauchy problem with smooth data that we can solve. We find solutions of the approximate problem in some Sobolev-valued $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ space (e.g. $C([0,T];H^s(\mathbb{R}))$, $L^p(0,T,H^s(\mathbb{R}))$ or similar).  And now we have a solution of approiximate problem that depends on parameter $\epsilon$. In order to get back on the initial problem we should let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

**My question is:** what do we need in order to pass to the limit  $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ (and then get a connection with a solution of the Riemann problem)? Generally I've always thought that this is possible either directly, by using some compactness lemma or with some energy estimates, but I am not sure how to do it in this case. Here on the one side we have a classical smooth solution, and  on the other side, after we let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, we should get discontinuous (weak) solution possibly in some other space. So we have different type of solutions.

Also if anyone know any paper/book where pde problem similar to this is studied let me know. I am interested in problems where we change initial condition to the smoooth one, than solve the "approximation problem" and than connected that solution with the solution of the original problem. It could be by letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ directly or using some theorem.

Comment: For the Riemann problem, if you find the solution in $C([0,T]; H^s(\mathbb{R}))$ of the approximate solution, and take $\epsilon \to 0$, your time of solution $[0,T]$ goes to 0. So in the limit you will not get a solution. If you can prove that the time of solution $T$ is dependent only on a weaker norm (say $L^1$) in which $H^s$ is dense, then you can argue via density; but here the crucial issue is precisely that you cannot do so.

Comment: @WillieWong, thank you for the comment. I have a few follow up questions. Approximate problem has smooth (in this case $C^4$ at least) initial conditions and now it is a Cauchy problem. It has solution in $C([0,T];H^s(\mathbb{R}))$. But the limit i.e. Riemann solution is not there of course. Could it be in $C_w ([0,T];H^s(\mathbb{R}))$? And could you explain a bit more why the time of solution goes to zero? Also instead of $L^1$ could we use some measure space?

Comment: Okay, it depends a bit on the the value of $u_l$ and $u_r$ and the sign of $f(u)$. The Riemann problem that generates _rarefraction waves_ will have, upon smoothing, a smooth solution that exists for all time, and taking the limit you can actually get a solution that is smooth for all $t > 0$ (but NOT at $t = 0$). However, the Riemann problem that generates _shock waves_ you will expect that for smoothed initial data the onset of shock happens sooner and sooner as $\epsilon \to 0$. Solutions with shock (in this context, jump discontinuities) are not in $H^s$ for $s \geq \frac12$.

Comment: In this latter case, the issue has nothing to do with data. You declared a solution as a function that is in $C([0,T]; H^s)$. (or something). It is manifest in conservation laws that jump discontinuities may arise from smooth initial data, and so within finite time you cannot have a function whose spatial regularity is at the $H^s$ level. For studying conservation laws past shocks, you need a notion of generalized solution that is compatible with these types of singularities.

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks for the follow up. Yes, when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ solution with shocks are not in $H^s, \: s\geq \frac{1}{2}$ i.e. shock solution has jump discontinuity in space and these $H^s$ functions are at least continuous. Also shocks are discontinuous in time so they can not be in $C([0,T];H^s)$. That's why I thought that I should use space such as $C_w([0,T];\mathcal{M})$ - weakly continuous in $t$, and belong to the space of Radon measures (in $x$) for example. And here the notion of the solution would use some test functions (so I could consider it as generalized solution).

Comment: If you are using such spaces, then you don't really need smoothing, do you? This is getting very close to the standard methods, maybe you can just read something like Lax's notes and see how he does it.

Comment: @WillieWong, usually for this type of spaces I would not need smoothing. But for the problem I am working on I need smoothing (I approximate original problem one more time and for this approximate problem I need smooth initial conditions). What standard method do you have in mind? (Send a reference if possible). And thanks again for the help.

Comment: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611970562.ch1 comes to mind.

Comment: @WillieWong, thank you. I will check it out soon.